# Remove blue colored row from DataGridView WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

When I fill a DataGridView row by row (calling it's add function), the top row gets blue colored.
It's not selected because I tried ClearSelection() also but it didnt work.
It's giving the wrong illusion that the first row is selected.

How to get rid of it?

```
 void FillDGV()
    {
        dataGridViewParties.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewParties.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridViewParties.Columns[i].Width = this.Width / dataGridViewParties.Columns.Count;
        }


        DataTable partyTbl = UtilityClass.GetDataTable(@"SELECT [PartyID]
                                                        ,[PartyName]
                                                        ,[PartyAddress]
                                                        ,[PartyState]
                                                        ,[PartyCity]
                                                        ,[PartyPhone]
                                                        FROM [VegiManager].[dbo].[Parties]
                                                        WHERE [PartyName] LIKE '" + textBoxPartySearch.Text + "%' ");
        foreach (DataRow dr in partyTbl.Rows)
        {
            dataGridViewParties.Rows.Add(1);

            dataGridViewParties.Rows[dataGridViewParties.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = dr["PartyID"].ToString();
            dataGridViewParties.Rows[dataGridViewParties.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = dr["PartyName"].ToString();
            dataGridViewParties.Rows[dataGridViewParties.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = dr["PartyAddress"].ToString();
            dataGridViewParties.Rows[dataGridViewParties.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value = dr["PartyState"].ToString();
            dataGridViewParties.Rows[dataGridViewParties.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[4].Value = dr["PartyCity"].ToString();
            dataGridViewParties.Rows[dataGridViewParties.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[5].Value = dr["PartyPhone"].ToString();
        }

        if (dataGridViewParties.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridViewParties.ClearSelection();
            dataGridViewParties.CurrentCell = null;
        }
    }
```

In the debugger I found that CurrentCell is already null before DataGridViewParties.CurrentCell = null; executes.

This question http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c440c4f6-6dfc-47b6-97c0-1ce49c105b64/ is also related to it but does not offer a solution.

EDIT: Its weird but it works for Load event, I was doing it in constructor.
I want that when the first row is selected and when the user presses the UP arrow key, the focus moves to a certain textbox. But in this case it does not work (first row appears blue)

```
    private void dataGridViewInwards_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && dataGridViewParties.SelectedRows.Count > 0 && dataGridViewParties.SelectedRows[0].Index == 0)
        {
            textBoxPartySearch.Focus();
            dataGridViewParties.ClearSelection();
            dataGridViewParties.CurrentCell = null;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && dataGridViewParties.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        {
            textBoxPartySearch.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it is not selected, but it may be the focused row

Comment: I just checked and found that a textbox has the focus.

Comment: I tried dataGridView.ClearSelection() and works fine for me. Can you share the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this along with the `ClearSelection` you will need to set one more property

Try this in the `DataBindingComplete`

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
```

*EDIT*

Based on your comments you can modify the code as

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 0)
{                   
     this.ActiveControl = textBoxPartySearch;
     dataGridView1.Refresh();
     dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
     dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I am actually filling the datagridview row by row(not databinding it). Where should I put that code ? I tried putting it after datagridview has been filled but it did not work !

Comment: I tried adding rows and setting the statement after that .. works for me. Check if you are performing any other action

Comment: Yes i have also done in similar fashion, Do you perform any operations after this `FillDGV()` is called ? It might be something trivial .. check that (I have done this code in Load of the form)

Comment: OK, I was doing it in the constructor.It works in Load event. But I am using one code to move the focus to top textbox when the first row is selected and the user presses the UP arrow but it does not work. See my update in question.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, what do you mean by top textbox ? what do you want on arrow press ?

Comment: Ok .. use `this.ActiveControl = textBoxPartySearch;` instead of setting `Focus` and you should be fine

Comment: Bro, I used this if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && dataGridViewParties.SelectedRows.Count > 0 && dataGridViewParties.SelectedRows[0].Index == 0)
            {
                dataGridViewParties.ClearSelection();
                dataGridViewParties.CurrentCell = null;
                this.ActiveControl = textBoxPartySearch;
            } but it did not work, Please suggest.

Comment: I believe `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index ==0` might be a culprit here , Is you code executed did you check via Debug if it actually executes the code ? try removing the mentioned condition and then see

Comment: This would be a better condition `e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 0`

Comment: I checked in debugger and found that the code indeed executes but still that blue row appears.

Comment: please check my updated answer ..hope that would help you out

Comment: That worked ! Thanks for your patience ! That is weird why DataGridView is like that !

Answer (score 5):

I tried the above methods but nothing worked for me.

Finally, I just decided to set the default colors for selected cells to be the same as non-selected cells.

Then, in the cell click method, I set them back. That way nothing appears selected until its clicked, which was sufficient for my application. Here's the code I used in the click method to set everything back to normal:

```
dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.Window;
```

Annoyingly, the ClearSelection method actually works just fine if I put it in a button, but if I create the control which contains the datagrid, load some data into it, and then try to clear it right then, it doesn't work. I wish I knew why...

Comment: Yes, the datagridview is very buggy.Hope MS takes care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ClearSelection() to VisibleChanged event as follows:

```
private void datagridview1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
datagridview1.ClearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After three hours of troubleshooting this, I've figured it out:  Your `DataGridView` needs to be displayed on the screen *before* calling `dataGridView.ClearSelection()`.

How I know this works:

I have two `DataGridViews`, each in a different panel.  Only one panel is visible at a time.  In the panel that's initially visible, the `DataGridView` has never ignored my call to `ClearSelection()`, so I've never seen a row selected right away.

I used to populate the other `DataGridView` and clear its selection before showing the panel that contains it, but that top row was always still highlighted. I changed my code to display the other panel before clearing the `DataGridView`'s selection, and the call to `ClearSelection()` worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

In `Form.Shown` Event Just do a:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
```