# DataGridView properties not being set when called from Form Load

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

i have one combobox and datagridview. on combobox index change datatable is change.

```
userDetailGridView.Rows[4].Selected = true;
```

when first time page is load this is not working. but next time when i change combo box then 4th row is selected. but when page load first row is selected.

why this code is not working on form load.

Comment: Where have you given that code you showed here?

Comment: hmmm, what are you trying to achieve? which events are triggered when form is loaded? (if you have the code in combobox_indexchanged and this method isnt triggered, then this wont work, then you need to put it in an init() method which is called after initialising components)

Comment: I think you are looking something on these lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960897/remove-blue-colored-row-from-datagridview-winforms/5960988#5960988

Comment: Did you put the above code in your OnLoad event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I fully understand the problem, but as far as I can understand, it is most likely that you have the selection code executing before the GridView is being populated with the data.  Therefore, the GridView will not have 4 rows yet to select from.

You will need to add an event handler for when DataBindingComplete where you can use the code you have above.  I would also suggest using the ClearSelection() prior to making your select.

Refer to the msdn for this event handlers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the contents of a control until the form is showing. In the `Form_Load` event, call `Me.Show()`, then add your code to edit the control. This is true for all controls I believe.

Example:

```
Form_Load()
     ....
     Me.Show()
     TextBox.Focus()
End Sub
```