# the first cell in my table is automatic blue c#

Tags: c#

When i populate my datagridview the first cell in the datagridview is always blue. The data grid view is populated with DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. it's like I have pressed the cell but I have not.it is like that with every table I create. i dont want it to be blue, can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

By default, there's always a selection on a `DataGridView`. If you don't want it, you can do:

```
// hides the "blue"
theDataGridView.ClearSelection();
// hides the "focus rectangle"
theDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
```

As soon as the control gets focused again, you'll have a focus rect though.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default the selection mode will be singlecell you can change that. Also in code behind you can set the dgGridView.SelectedIndex = -1
or clearselection like that

[Remove blue colored row from DataGridView WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960897/remove-blue-colored-row-from-datagridview-winforms)

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView.ClearSelection();
```

and then set the current cell property to null

```
  dataGridView.CurrentCell = null; // for no focus
```